# How to add new lines and identation to XML string using CodeMirror?

Tags: html, xml, codemirror

XML is received as one line string. I need to format it and put into CodeMirror editor. I could not find anything useful for this matter in [manual](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html).  Then I tried google-code-prettify with no success. Search on SO gave nothing usable. How to prettify `xml` and put it into `CodeMirror` editor?

```
var editor2 = CodeMirror(document.getElementById("xmlResponseTextarea"), {
        lineNumbers: true,
        mode: "xml"
    });
var pretty = prettyPrintOne(data, 'xml');
editor2.setValue(pretty);
```

**UPDATE:**

I actually was looking for AutoFormatting option. I solved it by :

```
cm.execCommand("selectAll");
cm.execCommand("indentAuto");
```

Comment: your solution sounds sweet! please post this as an answer, for the benefit of others :)

Answer (score 0):

*After* setting the value, iterate over the lines and indent them in the document:

```js
doc.eachLine(function (line) {
    cm.indentLine(doc.getLineNumber(line));
});
```

See [`indentLine()`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#indentLine) on the CodeMirror documentation.